# Where to start with backup/restore of Hyper-V in C#?

Tags: c#, backup, hyper-v

Where one would start to learn how to interact with Hyper-V thru C# to able to backup and restore virtual machines (preferably with snapshots and everything else related to backup)? I tried finding some examples / information on how to start but couldn't find anything. Maybe I was just asking wrong questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582.aspx) to access the virtualization services.

Documentation and samples related to the WMI virtualization classes are available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136988.aspx).

Comment: Here are some samples for WMI and Hyper-V Backup: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Hyper-V-recovery-snapshot-ea72320c

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: https://hypervbackup.codeplex.com/

Disclaimer: I'm not involved in that project!

The main goal of this project is to provide a very easy and powerful free tool to backup and restore Hyper-V virtual machines, in standalone and clustered (CSV) environments, overcoming all the limitations that a generic tool like Diskshadow provides.

This tool targets Windows 2008, Windows 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2012. All the corresponding core and free Hyper-V editions are also supported!

HVBackup supports app consistent and crash consistent backups through the Hyper V VSS writer component integrated in the operating system.

There are quite a few expensive commercial solutions on the market supporting this scenario, but this is the first open source one, based on the research we did before publishing the project.

We integrated this tool in our datacenter's production environment management infrastructure, which means that it undergoes continuous testing in a real world environment :-)

HVBackup can be invoked from the command line, scripted with Powershell or integrated in any .Net program through it's class library.

The backup process generates a separate zip file for each virtual machine in the specified output directory, containing all the files owned by the VM and identified for backup by the VSS Hyper-V provider.